# Why doesn't small integer caching seem to work with int objects from the round() function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Can you please explain why this happens in Python v3.8?

```
a=round(2.3)
b=round(2.4)

print(a,b)
print(type(a),type(b))

print(a is b)
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

Output:

```
2 2
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
False
2406701496848
2406701496656
>>>
```

2 is within the range of the small integer caching. So why are there different objects with the same value?

Comment: The small int cache isn't a guarantee, just an implementation detail. The question is interesting from an academic perspective (I just tried to trace it, and it seems like it should be going from `round` to `float.__round__` which calls `PyLong_FromDouble`, which for small values would call `PyLong_FromLong`, and that should check the cache, so I'm not sure why it's not behaving as expected), but it's an implementation detail, and not a guaranteed one, so relying on it at all indicates badly written code.

Comment: Can't reproduce... in Python 3.9 :-) (but can in 3.8)

Comment: @superbrain: Found the change. The code path changed as an optimization for converting C `double`s to `PyLong`s, and it looped in the small `int` cache check by side-effect.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, when I first saw that change, I thought they just moved the optimization from the `__round__` implementation to where it's now. But looking again I see it was in the `__trunc__` implementation. And indeed, in 3.8, `1.2.__round__() is 1` gives me `False` while `1.2.__trunc__() is 1` already gives me `True`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like in 3.8, `PyLong_FromDouble` (which is what `float.__round__` ultimately delegates to) [explicitly allocates a new `PyLong` object and fills it in manually](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/longobject.c#L408), without normalizing it (via the `IS_SMALL_INT` check and `get_small_int` cache lookup function), so it doesn't check the small `int` cache to resolve to the canonical value.

This will change in 3.9 as a result of [issue 37986: Improve perfomance of PyLong_FromDouble()](https://bugs.python.org/issue37986), which now has it delegate to `PyLong_FromLong` when the `double` is small enough to be losslessly represented as a C `long`. By side-effect, this will use the small `int` cache, as `PyLong_FromLong` reliably normalizes for small values.